# Facebook login button doesn't render after refresh

Tags: html, facebook, authentication, fbml, render

I have been experimenting using a Facebook login button on my website. The login button renders correctly the first time I access the page and when I arrive at the page through a link, however, if I refresh using cmd+r in Firefox and Safari for Mac, the button does not render.

Does anyone have any ideas? An example of the button can be found on the homepage at - http://www.totalwindsurf.co.uk

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the fbml version You could try to render the button using javascript, and xfbml parse.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

```
    <div id="build1"></div>
<script>
    window.Build1 = function(){
    Cbuild1 = document.getElementById('build1');
    Cbuild1.innerHTML = "";
    Cbuild1.innerHTML = "<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>";
    FB.XFBML.parse(Cbuild1);
    }
    setTimeout("Build1()",1000);
</script>
```

Comment: So far so good, thanks! Any ideas why I would be having problems with the fbml version?